# Using Google's Custom Search api

Tags: programming, python

I am currently working for a social media site. We would like to use Google Custom Search Engine API and derive analytical insights from the results. My choice of development platform is R or Python. The following source code in R is used to fetch details about a person, whose details are publically available.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
searchword="Bill+Gates"
query=paste("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=ENGINE_ID&q=",searchword,"&alt=json&num=7",sep = "")
results <- content(GET(query))
print(results)
results_JSON <- toJSON(results)
results_JSON <- fromJSON(results_JSON)
results_df <- as.data.frame(results_JSON)
titles_df <- as.data.frame(results_df$items.title)
pagemap_df <-
  as.data.frame(results_df$items.pagemap) for (dfindex in 1:length(pagemap_df$person)) {
    if (!is.null(pagemap_df$person[[dfindex]]))
      locationdf = t(as.data.frame(unlist(pagemap_df$person[[dfindex]])))
  }
```

We plan to customize the results and display it other details in a separate format. On client side review of this code, I got the feedback that the use of custom search API in this manner is not within the terms and conditions provided by Google. Does this kind of operation from an application is not permitted? Once it is hosted, this will be blocked by Google? If it is allowed, We are planning to add credits to the paid API program.

Comment: This might be better suited for stackoverflow and tagged `google-custom-search` as that is what the Google developer site for CSE suggests.

Comment: also, not sure if google's custom search api is open...most of their products are not....